# Why won't my code return what I want it to?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have some code that doesn't return what I want it to.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] swapped= {86,5,3,14,5,26,7,8,9,10,928,40};
       int[] swaps=swap(swapped);
       for(int num: swaps){
      System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
  }
  public static int[] swap(int[] swapping){
    int max=swapping[0];
    int min=swapping[0];
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]>max){
        swapping[i]=max;
      }
      if(swapping[i]<min){
        swapping[i]=min;
      }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]==max){
        swapping[i]=min;
      }
      if(swapping[i]==min){
        swapping[i]=max;
      }
    }
    return swapping;
  }
}
```

The code is supposed the swap the biggest and smallest number in an array but instead it only returns the very first element in the array for each element. So if the array is {1,3,6,2} then it'll print out 1 1 1 1 instead of 6 3 1 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code is trying to do (unsuccessfully though) is to find the min and the max items of the array, but even this does not succeed because you don't save the max and min values with an assignment like:

```
max = swapping[i];
```

but you use the opposite:

```
swapping[i] = max;
```

Anyway, even if you did it correctly you would have to reiterate the array with another loop to make the swap.
You can avoid this 2nd loop if in the 1st you save not the values of the min and max but their indices:

```
public static int[] swap(int[] swapping){
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < swapping.length; i++){
        if(swapping[i] > swapping[max]){
            max = i;
        }
        if(swapping[i] < swapping[min]){
            min = i;
        }
    }
    int temp = swapping[min];
    swapping[min] = swapping[max];
    swapping[max] = temp;
    return swapping;
}
```

Result:

```
86 5 928 14 5 26 7 8 9 10 3 40
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring in your first for loop.

```
if(swapping[i]>max){
  swapping[i]=max;
}
```

Since max is 1 at first. When swapping[i] is any value (say e.g. 3 for i=1).

your code becomes this

```
if(3>1){
  swapping[i]=1;
}
```

You are basically replacing any value greater that what you have in max with the value of max. What you want to do is the opposite.

```
if(swapping[i]>max){
  max=swapping[i];
}
```

You also have a few more bugs but this is the answer to your current bug.

Seems like the function you wanted to write is this.

```
  public static int[] swap(int[] swapping){
    int max=swapping[0];
    int min=swapping[0];
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]>max){
        max = swapping[i];
      }
      if(swapping[i]<min){
        min = swapping[i];
      }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]==max){
        swapping[i]=min;
      }else {
        if(swapping[i]==min){
          swapping[i]=max;
        }
      }
    }
    return swapping;
  }
```

There are more efficient solutions but this one does the least alterations to your code.

Comment: Oh thank you, I'll see if any more bugs raise issues.

Answer (score 0):

You’re never saving the max and min values in the loop.  Also, you aren’t swapping the  values correctly.

swapping[i] = max and swapping[i] = min only set the array values to 1, the current value of max and min.

You need

```
  if(swapping[i]>max){
     max = swapping[i];
  }
  if(swapping[i]< min){
     min = swapping[i];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the maximum and the minimum index in order to do the swap:

```
public static int[] swap(int[] swapping){
    //Initializing values and indexes
    int max = swapping[0];
    int min = swapping[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    //The maximum and minimum values and indexes so far were the 0'th, so we start from the first
    for (int index = 1; index < swapping.length; index++) {
        if (max < swapping[index]) {
            max = swapping[index];
            maxIndex = index;
        }
        if (min > swapping[index]) {
            min = swapping[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    swapping[maxIndex] = min;
    swapping[minIndex] = max;
    return swapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in the first loop of swap, you would save the value of min and max

and also, when you check if `swapping[i]==max` or `swapping[i]==min` then you should use an **else if** because otherwise in case of `swapping[i]==max` you first write the min value in `swipping[i]` and then you check if `swapping[i]==min` (and now is true) the value of `swapping[i]` will be replaced with the max value.
Here is an example of what I think is the right approach (note line 15, 18, 24)

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] swapped= {86,5,3,14,5,26,7,8,9,10,928,40};
      int[] swaps=swap(swapped);
      for(int num: swaps){
        System.out.print(num + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
  public static int[] swap(int[] swapping){
    int max=swapping[0];
    int min=swapping[0];
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]>max){
        max = swapping[i];
      }
      if(swapping[i]<min){
        min = swapping[i];
      }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<swapping.length;i++){
      if(swapping[i]==max){
        swapping[i]=min;
      } else if(swapping[i]==min){
        swapping[i]=max;
      }
    }
    return swapping;
  }
}
```